# PHP Mailer envia correos a spam y no a la bandeja de entrada

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buen dia, estoy enviando correos por medio de phpmailer pero llegan a no deseados especialmente en destinos @hotmail.com alguna idea que puede ser?

```
<?php
    require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail=new PHPmailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host='gator4025.hostgator.com';          
            $mail->Port=465;
            $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';

            $mail->Username='comercial@tecflucol.com';
            $mail->Password='mypass';

            $mail->setFrom('comercial@tecflucol.com','Solicitudes Tecflucol');
            $mail->Sender='comercial@tecflucol.com';
            $mail->addReplyTo('comercial@tecflucol.com','Solicitudes Tecflucol');
            $mail->addAddress(prueba125474522@hotmail.com);
            $mail->isHTML(false);
            $mail->Subject='Confirmacion solicitud de instalacion de agua numero: '.$nuevo_id;
            $mail->Body='Has realizado una solicitud de instalacion de agua para su hogar, con numero : '.$nuevo_id."\r\n"."\r\n".
            'Le estaremos contactando al numero proporcionado: '.$celular."\r\n".
            'Gracias por usar nuestros servicios'."\r\n".
            'Cordialmente:'."\r\n".
            'Tecflucol';

            if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mensaje no enviado <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else {
        echo "Mensaje enviado";
            }
?>
```

Comment: Revisa el código fuente de uno de los correos que te está entrando en la carpeta Spam. Allí te dirá qué filtros no está pasando el mensaje. Hay tres tipos de filtros que debes configurar en tu servidor de correos: `SPF`,  `DKIM` y `DMARC`. Es realmente algo complicado hacer esas configuraciones, las cuales ayudan a que tu correo no sea considerado como Spam. Recuerdo haber encontrado en la ayuda de Google explicaciones sobre cómo hacerlo según el hosting que estés usando. En cualquier caso, el código fuente del mensaje te informará del problema, revísalo.

Comment: Otra cosa que puede ayudar es autentificar el SMTP, [como explica esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30238018/5587982). Lee también [este hilo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1412) donde se habla sobre las configuraciones de filtro anti spam que mencioné antes: `SPF, DKIM,  DMARC`. Ten en cuenta que si se detecta envío masivo desde tu cuenta te pueden meter en una lista negra, etc.

Comment: Hola, realizando un desarrollo también me sucedía lo mismo. El problema suele estar en la autenticación de tu host en este caso gator4025.hostgator.com
Es un poco complicado de resolver al menos rápidamente jaja, pero piensa que sino cualquiera se pone a poner cualquier host desconocido y enviar mail spam como si nada.